# override data in T-SQL

Tags: t-sql

I'm trying to figure out the most concise way to achieve the following result set:
[image]

given this input data:
[image]

Notice that rows 1 and 3 of the input data consist of the same item+bucket combination.  Rows with a source of 'mandate' are supposed to take precedence over rows with a source of 'forecast' for matching item+bucket combinations when generating the result set.  In cases where item+bucket combinations have no duplication due to difference sources, those rows are to appear in the final result set regardless of their source.

Here is the code for the input data:

```html
declare @t table
(
  source varchar(20) not null,
  item int not null,
  bucket date not null,
  quantity int not null,
  primary key clustered (source, item, bucket)
);

insert into @t values
('forecast', 8501, '9/1/2016', 100),
('forecast', 8528, '9/1/2016', 100),
('mandate', 8501, '9/1/2016', 200),
('mandate', 8530, '9/1/2016', 200);

select * from @t;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ROW_NUMBER and order by the [source] field, descending (so "m..." appears first):

```
declare @t table
(
  source varchar(20) not null,
  item int not null,
  bucket date not null,
  quantity int not null,
  primary key clustered (source, item, bucket)
);

insert into @t values
('forecast', 8501, '9/1/2016', 100),
('forecast', 8528, '9/1/2016', 100),
('mandate', 8501, '9/1/2016', 200),
('mandate', 8530, '9/1/2016', 200);

; WITH QtyRank
AS (SELECT *
        , qRank = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [item] ORDER BY [source] DESC)
    FROM @t
    )
SELECT *
FROM QtyRank
WHERE QtyRank.qRank = 1 ;
```

Comment: Now that is concise!

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```html
with
overlap as
(
  select t2.*
  from @t t1
  inner join @t t2
  on t1.item = t2.item
  and t1.bucket = t2.bucket
  where t1.source = 'forecast' and t2.source = 'mandate'
)
select t.item, t.bucket, t.quantity
from @t t
left outer join overlap o
on t.item = o.item
and t.bucket = o.bucket
where o.item is null
union all
select item, bucket, quantity from overlap;
```

Not sure it's the most concise approach though.